# How do I get scale_x_continuous to show full range?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot two functions with ggplot, using the following code:

```
ggplot() + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 12, by=1)) +
  xlab("Price") + 
  ylab("Quantity")+
  geom_function(fun = function(x) 1200-100*x) +
  geom_function(fun = function(x) 100*x)
```

[ggplot output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8GyR.png)
However, when plotted it appears like this, not following the range 0-12 directed in the scale_x_continuous command? Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: You don't have anything mapped to an `x` aesthetic, so you need to use `limits` ins `scale_x_continuous()` to set the range you want plotted, e.g., `limits = c(0, 12)`

Comment: Thank you very much!! That did it for that issue - however now the by=1 gets ignored and the scale of the x axis is (0, 2.5, 5.0, 7,5, 10.0, 12.5). Any clue how to fix that?

Comment: I can't reproduce. When I use `scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 12, by=1), limits = c(0, 12))` everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Jonas can you post your latest code here? I suspect a simple typo mistake.

You can also define a range for you break like

```
    breaks = seq(from = 0, to = 12, by = 1.0))
```

Edit added code:

I get what you want with this code in https://rdrr.io/snippets/

```
    library(ggplot2)


    ggplot() +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 12, by=1), limits = c(0, 12)) + 
    xlab("Price") + 
    ylab("Quantity")+
    geom_function(fun = function(x) 1200-100*x) +
    geom_function(fun = function(x) 100*x)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ggplot() + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 12, by = 1),
                     limits = c(0, 12)) +
  xlab("Price") + 
  ylab("Quantity")+
  geom_function(fun = function(x) 1200-100*x) +
  geom_function(fun = function(x) 100*x)
```

The codes above gave me the plot below:

[image: plot]